# Type error when using 1 list over another?

Tags: python, error-handling

`keyw` does not work in place of keywords:
`keyw` is similar to keywords except for its sorted on element occurrences.

```
keywords = cat.value_counts().keys().tolist()
nums = Counter(cat).most_common()
keyw = ([num for num, _ in nums])

def findcuisine(col):
  for word in keywords:
    if word in col:`
      return word

df2['Cuisine'] = df2['categories'].apply(findcuisine)
yelp_df = df2.drop(columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])
```

When I swap **keywords** list for **keyw** I get:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

For context cat is a dataframe column which includes strings like

```
['Pizza', 'Sandwiches', 'Mexican', 'American (Traditional)', 'Fast Food', 'Chinese', 'American (New)', 'Italian'...]
```

Comment: If you print `keywords` and `keyw`, how do they compare?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]